# ENOENT error: no such file or directory found, open 'node:stream'

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, jestjs

I am currently trying to test a new implementation. One of the dependencies of the functions of my new implementation uses the Writable module from node:stream to create a writable stream. My problem is when trying to run the suit of tests I get this error.

```
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'node:stream'

      at Runtime.readFile (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1987:21)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@uktvtech/common-utils/src/fileTransferProtocol/getFTPClient.ts:6:1)
```

I'm assuming there must be some error on how node is accessing the the directory library for node:stream. How do I fix / change this?

Comment: Can you provide the code?

Comment: I'm also facing this type of issue using jest. Mine is with node:url. I have ts file with class in it. In that file I have import from cookie-agent. When I try to execute the test it fails with this error.
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'node:url'

      at Runtime.readFile (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1987:21)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/http-cookie-agent/dist/http/create_cookie_agent.js:8:39)

Comment: @GjorgjiVladimirovDzole What also worked for me was bumping up the version number to the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem with a `require("constants")` call in the `iso-constants` library when running jest tests. In my case someone else had already sent a [pull request with a workaround](https://github.com/hugomrdias/iso-constants/pull/131) for the `iso-contants` library, so I simply added overrides to my package.json until the pull request is fixed:

```
"resolutions": {
    "iso-constants": "git+https://github.com/inverted-capital/iso-constants.git#patch-1"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "iso-constants": {
      ".": "git+https://github.com/inverted-capital/iso-constants.git#patch-1"
    }
  },
```